# How do I search all indexed locations in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I have a dual-boot system with two copies of windows and six harddrives with one partition each.

How do I perform a search in all indexed locations across disks without touching any non-indexed locations?

It is important that the search can be performed in the background while swiching applications.

The start menu search does a wide search but it stops searching as soon as you try to do something while waiting as the start menu closes.

I've also tried searching in the Computer node in Windows Explorer but I believe that it will attempt to search outside indexed locations as windows explorer is capable of a slow search outside indexed locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit Win+F.  Then start typing.

Blah. 30 chars.